# String parsing by character in PHP without foreach

Tags: php, string, parsing

I would like to do the following conversion in php:

```
from: "0110001" to: "Tuesdays, Wednesdays, Sundays".
```

Bonus points for doing this one:

```
from: "0110001" to: "Tuesdays, Wednesdays and Sundays".
```

The input are seven characters, each represents a day of week.

How can I do that without a foreach loop? I would like to use array_walk or array_reduce.

---

Working solution but with a foreach :

```
<?php

    function parseDays($str) {
      $days = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
      $result = array();
      foreach (str_split($str) as $k=>$v) {
        if ($v == '1') {
          $result[] = $days[$k];
        }
      }
      return join(', ', $result);
    }

echo parseDays("0110001");
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: @pinouchon so you want to replace the last "," with " and" ?

Comment: write a function that does this conversion (you say, you have it already) and pass that function as callback to array_map

Comment: @pinouchon: Post it anyway. Showing what you have is going to make people appreciate the question better.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV No, each bit in his array represents a day of the week, which he wants to display using their respective names.

Comment: @JohnConde Here is my working version, but it's using foreach.

Comment: @pinouchon Why are you trying to avoid a foreach? `array_walk` will internally loop over an array. It's not saving you time.

Comment: @ColinMorelli Indeed. This is also to see if the code can be made more readable without one.

Comment: most likely it will get less readable.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the first version with just built-in functions:

```
$daynames = array(
    'Mondays', 'Tuesdays', // etc
);

$in = "0110001";
echo implode(', ', array_intersect_key($daynames, array_filter(str_split($in))));
```

How this works:

1. Split the input into an array of ones and zeroes; crucially, the keys of this array match the keys of `$daynames`.
2. Filter out zeroes; fortunately `array_filter` preserves keys.
3. Use `array_intersect_key` to map keys to values inside `$daynames`.
4. Use `implode` to make a comma-separated list of the above.

If you want to convert the last comma to `"and"`, the most terse way would be a regular expression (personally I find this solution questionable although it's undeniably effective):

```
echo preg_replace('/,(?=[^,]+$)/', ' and', implode(...));
```

### However

Please don't forget that the best kind of code is code which does not exist (guaranteed zero bugs!), and second best is code that you understand with your eyes closed.

The code above certainly does *not* fall into either of those categories; my professional recommendation would be to use `foreach` if that results in code that is familiar to whoever is going to maintain it.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need it to do

```
function convertDays($input) {
    $days = array('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday');
    $dayNames = array_intersect_key($days, array_filter(str_split($input)));

    if (count($dayNames) < 2) {
        return implode(', ', $dayNames);
    }

    $commaSeparatedDays = array_slice($dayNames, 0, -1);
    return implode(', ', $commaSeparatedDays) . ' and ' . end($dayNames);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$bits = array();
$bits = str_split("0110001");

function print_day($key, $item) {

  $days_of_the_week = array(
    "0" => "Mondays",
    "1" => "Tuesdays",
    "2" => "Wednesdays",
    "3" => "Thursdays",
    "4" => "Fridays",
    "5" => "Saturdays",
    "6" => "Sundays",
  );

  if ($key) {
    echo $days_of_the_week[$item] . " ";
  }
}

array_walk($bits, 'print_day');

?>
```

Comment: That's what I had in mind in the beginning. But it's tricky to avoid the trailing space or ','.